# jQuery add .hover() to every anchor except those that already have effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I want to add .hover() to every anchor in my website, except those that already have .hover() [added .hover() separately before].

I have no idea how to do it in jQuery or if its possible.
If its not possible, I have another idea but again, I dont know how to do it or if its possible.

The idea goes like that: can I add .hover() effect to every anchor except those are in parent div with id "test" and those are in parent div with id "test2"?

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this, some of which are.

First

```
$('a').not('#test a, #test2 a');
```

Second

```
var divs_to_test = $('#test').add('#test2');
$('a').filter(function(){ 
    return !$(this).parent().is(divs_to_test); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
$('a').not($('#test a, #test2 a'))
```

To select all `<a>`s that are not in those elements.

Comment: Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (#test, #test2).

Comment: I would set your answer as accepted but interstellar_coder gave two ways & his similar way to yours is with less chars > therefore faster (for loading).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found for this is the somewhat less-than-concise:

```
$('a').filter(
    function() {
        if (!$(this).closest('div[id^="test"]').length) {
            return this;
        }
    }).hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wcaaw/).